# Activity onCreateView not always called on Android 8.0 / Oreo

Tags: android, android-activity, android-8.0-oreo

I'm receiving this crash:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML
>   file line #32: Class MyInterface is not a View

Before **Android O**, I'm initializing the `MyInterface` to a Subclass of `View` in `Activity.onCreateView` such as:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (name.equals(MyInterface.class.getName())) {
        View v = MyView.create(this, attrs);
        return v;
    }

    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}
```

This is the outline of the xml of the `Fragment` (Yes, not activity.):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <MyInterface
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Seems like this `onCreateView(String, Context, AttributeSet)` is not called in some circumstance on Android O?

I've tried the Android O behavior change doc but I didn't see anything around this function.

Comment: How is your “MyInterface” class code looks like?

Comment: @Nguyễn Hoài Nam It's simply an interface so should not be relevant here, I'll add some information around how I'm using it.

Comment: The reason I ask for it is because it seems that you use it in the xml file for the UI. Can you double check?

Comment: @Nguyễn Hoài Nam Yes, you're correct. We're using an interface in the xml and is utilizing onCreateView to swap in the actual implementation on the fly.

Comment: Unrelated: Choosing MyView implementation is it's own responsibility, it probably shouldn't depend on overriding an Activity method. There should be no interfaces in XML because only Views are able to be in the view tree. See source of CardView for an alternative. CardView chooses implementation once in a static variable. You could also choose implementation in View constructor based on Context. WebView does a similar thing too, just more complex.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec That's very helpful! Thanks! I'll take a look to see if we can improve the code that way.

Answer (score 0):

---

This post in bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1377819
Suggest that Firefox for Android is solving this by swapping from

`onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`

to

`onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`

to solve the problem. I'm going to try this but I guess someone might have a more detailed answer.

Comment: I thought that this overload is always called since Android 3 where it was introduced.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec Yeah, in bugzilla current evidence show that switching to the Android 3 version (with parent) fixes the problem while we were using the Android 1 version (without parent) and from our crash logs in Firefox for Android and another product which I am on, we're receiving crashes which shows the Android 1 version is not always called. (It used to before Android 8) And I feel like it's a good idea to share this since it's not documented in API change and the Android 1 version is not deprecated in Android 8.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're the only people using this architecture to do creation on the fly with this implementation, though.